# SpringBoot can't find bean to inject

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple SpringBoot app which has following classes:

`org.domain.abcpoc.controllers.DataController.java`

```
package org.domain.abcpoc.controllers;

import org.domain.abcpoc.entities.UserEntity;
import org.domain.abcpoc.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data")
public class DataController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @GetMapping()
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public UserEntity getUser() {
        return repo.findById("E7####J2####1##").orElse(null);
    }
}
```

`org.domain.abcpoc.repositories.UserRepository.java`

```
package org.domain.abcpoc.repositories;

import org.domain.abcpoc.entities.UserEntity;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, String> {
}
```

My main Spring class is:

```
package org.domain.abcpoc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ClmConnectorService {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClmConnectorService.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the exception I get is:

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field repo in org.domain.abcpoc.controllers.DataController required
> a bean of type 'org.domain.abcpoc.repositories.UserRepository' that
> could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'org.domain.abcpoc.repositories.UserRepository' in your
> configuration.

Could something else be the issue based on this exception and provided classes?
Database configuration?
pom.xml?

This is part of a Java module, could there be something in the parent pom.xml?

Comment: you gotta implement UserRepository and inject the implementation into the context with `@Component` or smth

Comment: Try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` in your main Spring class. You can add it right below `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: @StaticBeagle That fixed that issue. Thanks. You can write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation to the main `Spring` class as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ClmConnectorService {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClmConnectorService.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your interface with `@Repository` annotation, spring-boot auto-scanning will then create the bean of `UserRepository`.
`@EnableJpaRepositories` can also be used, its used when your application have multiple datasource configured